# Баг в stacksnippets.net / jQuery / Chrome?

Tags: дефект, статус-отложено, сниппеты

В [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/488282/7161) используется простейший сниппет с jQuery, который в Chrome вызывает ошибку SecurityError, если в поле input что-то ввести:

[image: консоль с ошибками]

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Sandbox access violation: 
Blocked a frame at "http://stacksnippets.net" from accessing a frame at "null".
Both frames are sandboxed and lack the "allow-same-origin" flag.
  un @ jquery.min.js:5
  rn @ jquery.min.js:5
  b.fn.extend.show @ jquery.min.js:5
  b.fn.(anonymous function) @ jquery.min.js:5
  (anonymous function) @ js:19
  b.event.dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
  v.handle @ jquery.min.js:3
```

[Тут пишут](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/240709), что этот баг был исправлен в англоязычном SO. Есть ли это обновления в Ru.SO?

Comment: 48.0.2564.97 (64-bit), OS X, вроде работает (в консоли такого сообщения нет).

Comment: Добавил скриншот, т.к. без него может быть непонятно, где искать вывод ошибки (например, я не знал).

Comment: Будете смеяться, но у меня (скопировал из About Google Chrome): `48.0.2564.97 (64-bit)` (идентично вашему), OS X 10.11.3 El Capitan – 
не работает! Может, РКН, DPI и погода как-то влияют?

Comment: 10.10.5 Yosemite )

Comment: Нужна метка [meta-tag:¯\_(ツ)_/¯]

Comment: Возможно причина в чем-то другом? У меня ошибка не воспроизводится. 47.0.2526.111 (64-bit) El Capitan 10.11.1

Comment: Возможно, в чём-то другом. Не у меня одного возникает ошибка, судя по комментариям и похожим вопросам на основном SO в предыдущие годы. UPd. проверил через буржуйский прокси – всё равно ошибка. Значит, это не провайдер и не РосКомНадзор.

Comment: В любом случае, добавил ошибку в базу дефектов. Возможно у кого-то получится воспроизвести. Спасибо!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky возможно, ее удастся воспроизвести, если в инпут на странице сниппета ввести любой текст. У меня воспроизводится.